# ImapSync between Exchange 2007 and Linux Postfix/Dovecot server

Tags: postfix, exchange, dovecot, imapsync

After running imapsync between an Exchange 2007 and a normal postfix/dovecot Linux server (we're in the process of migrating FROM Exchange to an OSS solution), and seeing that the process ran perfectly, we noticed something interesting.
Some of the migrated emails on their header only contains "from" in this way:

From: "John Doe"

...and not in this way:

From: "John Doe" john.doe@example.com

Then, every time somebody tries to reply or forward an old email, the new mail server doesn't get the real email address, and gives us an error, logically, because there is no email address with that form.

Is there any history on solving this kind of issues? Is it a flag I need to turn when running imapsync?
Thanks a lot in advance!
Best regards,

HeCSa.

Answer (score 0):

This is strange since imapsync doesn't change a byte on messages it transfers, unless told to do so with options like --regexmess or --pipemess

Can you show the headers of a broken message, both on source and destination?

Comment: Sure.  And something interesting we checked.  If we EXPORT the message from the Exchange server, the header contains this: `From:   User <user@example.com.ar>` but if we use imapsync between Exchange and the destination linux server, the header contains this: `From:   User`. Looks like if we export the messages, they go with the SMTP address, but if using imapsync, it doesn't. Strange, right? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's the first time I ear about this issue with Exchange, in twenty years... Another strange thing is that you wrote "Some of the migrated emails". So some messages are good and some are bad. Can you look at the messages in the source account using IMAP (with Thunderbird or Outlook)?

Comment: Hi Gilles! I'm doing exactly this today in the night. I used imapsync also in the past, but between Kolab 4 and Kolab 16, and everything worked like a charm. I'm starting to think that something may be configured in a strange way in the Exchange side. But as mentioned, today I'm performing that kind of tests.

Comment: If the mapping is known and fixed, imapsync can easily transform lines from "From:   User" to "From:   User <user@example.com.ar>"

Comment: Hi Gilles. Don't understand what you told about the mapping. Sorry, but can you explain it a bit? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you know that `From:   UserX` is always to be transformed to `From: userX@example.com.ar` then imapsync can do the transformation with `--regexmess 's{From:   UserX}{From: userX@example.com.ar}'`

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of your email client? Is it outlook?

Does the new emails occur to this issue?

I have found a blog on [How To Migrate Mailboxes Between IMAP Servers With imapsync](https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-migrate-mailboxes-between-imap-servers-with-imapsync), you could compare these steps in it with yours.

Comment: Hi! Yes, the origin server is Exchange, and the client we are using is Outlook. We used the same procedure shown in the page you sent. But the difference is that using imapsync it does not synchronize the entire headers, only the names of the recipients (John Dow) and not the SMTP address (john.doe@example.com). Thanks!